# Mac pro early 2008 won´t boot from pendrive with yosemite install app

Tags: macos, startup, mac-pro, bootable-disk

Mac pro 8 core early 2008 mountain lion installed.

I need to clean install Yosemite.

The pendrive does not show when you press alt, at the boot screen.
Nevertheless it shows on configuration startup disk, but is not booting from this volume.
The problem does not seem to be on the pendrive, since it works fine on a macbook, but does not show on the mac pro.

Please help, I´ve tried many times with no success.

Comment: does any other USB shows ?

Comment: Double check your model MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)

Comment: did you try the cmd+r

Comment: not much in the way of an answer, but I've never been able to get my Pro 3,1 to boot from an installer USB stick either. Just doesn't see it as bootable. Boots from an old DVD, but not USB - I've always used a spare drive to set up an OS; clone, install, test, remove old drive once happy.

Comment: might give this a try - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163327/85275 [ahh, but that's an MBP] … or http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20264/85275

Comment: well, blow me down - I just tried again with createinstallmedia & it worked. No clue what I did differently, apart from actually name my USB stick MyVolume, so I could just copy/paste the command from here - https://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201372

Comment: I believe 2008 macbook can't boot from usb.

Comment: @Buscar웃 do you have a source for that because I'm interested in answering this question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270074/what-are-the-1st-macbook-modelsyear-that-support-booting-from-usb

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to try...

If your Mac Pro has issues with booting from USB but will boot from a DVD, create a DVD from the USB installer. If you know how to do this then ignore the rest, grab a dual-layer DVD and get cracking. If not, read on...

First, mount your USB installer and then go to Disk Utility. Highlight the partition **Install OS X Yosemite** on the upper left pane then go to **File > New > Disk Image from "Install OS X Yosemite"**. Select **DVD/CD master** as the image format then hit the Save button when you're ready.

After a few moments you will have a disk image with the extension **.cdr**. This should be listed in Disk Utility on the lower left pane - highlight it and select **Burn**. You will need a dual-layer DVD for the burning operation.

*If* you can boot from the original Apple installation discs you *should* be able to boot from your newly created DVD, and hopefully it will appear as a boot option. Be warned, booting from the Yosemite DVD will take a small eternity, the installation itself will take quite a bit longer. Still, it's better to get there slowly than not at all ;-)

Alternatively, if you have a spare hard disk you could clone the Yosemite USB installer partition onto that using Disk Utility's Restore function. This should in theory be much quicker but I've not tried it out yet. I *have* had a successful boot and install from DVD on a MacBook (school's out for Easter so no access to a Mac Pro at the moment) so at least we know it's possible to create a working DVD installer.

**Small addition** - when installing from DVD the progress bars will lead to you to believe it's *actually* going to take forever, if not slightly longer. However, these do tend to stick at certain points while the system's busy and the whole process should be done in just over an hour.